# Is it possible to add more than 1 namespace in a same file (.cs)?

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces

I am currently learing C# so I would like to receive some support - is it possible to add more than one namespace in a same file?

Comment: Yes. it is possible. you could try that yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep. The following will compile no worries in a single file:

```
namespace Blah {
    public enum Stuff {A, B, C}
}
namespace Meh {
    public enum MoreStuff {A, B, C}
}
```

FYI, both the enums could be called Stuff if you wanted but I named them differently to keep the example simple. If they were both called Stuff then their fully-qualified names would be `Blah.Stuff` and `Meh.Stuff`

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, but I would advise against it as it might go against the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

check [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/53088/multiple-classes-in-a-single-cs-file-good-or-bad) for a discussion on having multiple classes in a single file (which is different, but I feel the reasoning for why/why not to do this is similar).

Is there any particular reason you want to do this?

Comment: Although putting multiple classes in a single file is not a good idea, it has nothing to do with SRP

Comment: @CodingYoshi Couldn't you consider a file to be a 'module' in the sense that if a file has multiple classes and does multiple things, it may make the code harder to read?

Comment: SRP is about classes having a specific responsibility. Putting multiple classes, that are doing that, into a single file does not change that fact.

Comment: I have 7 classes which implements one interface with only one method. In all classes implementation of that method is only one line of code. Having all classes in one file, will give me possibility to have all implementations in one place -> so one place to change when I want introduce new implementation or remove some...

Comment: Not at all, just wanted to know